# UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor!.UUIDString Swift 3 migration

Tags: swift, swift2, swift3, ios10, deviceid

I have the following code in swift 2

```
let deviceid = UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor!.UUIDString
```

This fails to compile.  I tried following suggestions from the auto-fix in xCode and I came up with this.

```
 let deviceid = UIDevice.currentDevice.identifierForVendor!.UUIDString
```

**However it still does not compile.  It says value of type 'UUID' has no member UUIDString'**

Comment: why the -1? I think this was legitimate question even if it did have a simple answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My advice - for these kind of issues - get straight into a playground

```
let deviceid = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString
```

[image: Playground xCode 8]